# Python - Want to insert blank columns into a existing written text or CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text

Want to insert a blank column " " like this in a text file(test14.csv) or else insert a full column within an existing csv.

The file has no header and lengthy data with irregular width.

Line 1 - You will get 4 column data with multiple seperator (; @ |).

Line 2 - You will get 7 column Data with same type of separators.

Line 3 - You will get 5 column data with same type of separators.

I tried with pd.read_csv, but because of the irregular width, there was an error.

Text File Sample:
Indices;AD;AD Indices ;*.ADS/I@ADS|7169
Indices;Arg;Main Arg Indices;*.SBI@SBI|49
Indices;Major Indices;Cboe Indices;Cboe - Eur Reg Indices;Cboe Europe AC sectors;Cboe Eur Tele Sec;BEPTEL*.BATI@BATI|7908
Eco&Fin Ind;Countries;Indo;Bank Indonesia;Statistics - Banking Stat;Foreign Exc Comm Bank Per;G20IDFXBKPR*.IDBI@IDBI|11266

so i want to do a text to column with | first, then @ and then semi colon after adding columns between them ..

i am successfully able to do 'Replace' and did the first 2 parts... only the insert column is pending.

Comment: Because text files are written line by line, adding a column means writing a whole new file.  If the file has varying columns really doesn't qualify as csv.  You could still read it line by line, and write modified lines to a new file.  But it won't make it make it any easier to use.

Comment: Would really need to see example data from your CSV to help with this one.